# Einstein Bot set single value from object to variable

Tags: apex, einstein, einstein-chatbot, bot

Apex action (APEX Invocable Method) in einstein bot accepts an object and also returns an object, is it possible from the method to return a single value? Please check the following syntax that helps me to query contact object by EMAIL address and return **lstContacts** but I just need to return ACCOUNTID. My requirement is based on the EMAIL address needed to get the ACCOUNTID.

In the einstein-bot is it possible to 'set value' from an object to a variable?

```
 List<ContactOutput> lstContacts = new List<ContactOutput>();
for(Contact contactRecord : [SELECT Id, Name, Email, AccountId, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Email IN : setContactEmailAddresses]){
                                                    
            ContactOutput output = new ContactOutput();
            output.contactRecord = contactRecord;
            lstContacts.add(output);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found and solve the issue: once the object is sent to the einstein bot, it cannot show any fields of the object. So in this case, a single data, integer, string, etc., can be returned through the apex class instead of an entire object or list. For example, I can retrieve an account name as a return value from the apex class. If I sent the entire account object, the einstein bot cannot show the account name only.